# vcpkg installed catch2 not detected in cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I am building unit test software for my library. I am using Catch2 Testing Framework Version 3.1.0

When I am trying to include the `catch_all` file in my aml_vector3_test.cpp but it is giving file not found error.

```
#include <catch2/catch_all.hpp> //Error in this line
#include "aml.h"
```

I had referred the [link](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/#cmake) for integration of vcpkg with my cmake prokect

I have tried both `set (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")` and `include ("D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")` in both my global CMake file and  test project cmake file but it still didn't help. I tried all permutation and combination with this.

Kindly note I have zero exposure to cmake and have no idea what I am doing.

Project Structure

```
aml
 |--CMakeLists.txt (CMake File 1)
 |--CMakeSettings.json
 |--aml
 |   |--CMakeLists.txt (CMake File 2)
 |   |--aml.h
 |   |--aml_vector3.cpp
 |   |--aml_vector3.h
 |--example
 |   |--CMakeLists.txt (CMake File 3)
 |   |--main.cpp
 |--test
 |   |--CMakeLists.txt (CMake File 4)
 |   |--main.cpp
 |   |--aml_vector3_test.cpp
```

CMake1 (Global CMake)

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
project ("AttitudeMathLibrary")

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("aml")
add_subdirectory ("test")
add_subdirectory ("example")

#enable_testing()
#add_test(test_all aml_vector3_test/aml_test)
```

Cmake2 (Main Library CMake)

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for aml_vector3, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project(aml)
# Add source to this project's executable.
# add_executable (aml_vector3 "aml_vector3.cpp" "aml_vector3.h" "aml.h")
# target_sources ("aml_vector3.cpp" "aml_vector3.h" "aml.h")
set (SRC_CPP_AML "aml_vector3.cpp" "aml_vector3.h" "aml.h")
# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.

add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_CPP_AML})

target_include_directories (${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

CMake3 (Example Project CMake)

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for aml_vector3, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project (aml_example)
# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} aml)

install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

CMake 4 (Unit Test Camke)

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for aml_vector3, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
#set (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
include ("D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
project (aml_test)

find_package(catch2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME}  "main.cpp" "aml_vector3_test.cpp")
include_directories(${CATCH2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} aml)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} catch2)
# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

CMakeSettings.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE",
          "value": "Debug",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX",
          "value": "C:/Users/darksorrow/source/repos/aml_vector3/out/install/x64-Debug",
          "type": "PATH"
        },
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM",
          "value": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe",
          "type": "FILEPATH"
        },
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE",
          "value": "D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
message ("CATCH2_INCLUDE_DIRS : ${CATCH2_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

prints

```
[CMake] CATCH2_INCLUDE_DIRS : D:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include
```

Other Codes:

aml.h

```
#pragma once
// Helper file - Imports all Attitude Math Library Files in a single file.
// This is a convenience file for the user

#include "aml_vector3.h"
```

aml_vector.h

```
#include <iostream>

namespace aml
{
    class Vector3
    {
    public:
        union
        {
            double data[3];
            struct
            {
                double x, y, z;
            };
        };
        //Constructors
        Vector3();
        Vector3(double value);
        Vector3(double x, double y, double z);
        Vector3(double data[3]);

        //Operator Assignment (Vector)
        Vector3& operator+=(const Vector3& rhs);
        Vector3& operator-=(const Vector3& rhs);
        Vector3& operator*=(const Vector3& rhs);
        Vector3& operator/=(const Vector3& rhs);

        //Operator Assignment (Scalar)
        Vector3& operator+=(double s);
        Vector3& operator-=(double s);
        Vector3& operator*=(double s);
        Vector3& operator/=(double s);

    };
}
```

aml_vector.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include "aml_vector3.h"

namespace aml
{
    Vector3::Vector3() : x(0.0), y(0.0), z(0.0)
    {
    }

    Vector3::Vector3(double value) : x(value), y(value), z(value)
    {
    }

    Vector3::Vector3(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {
    }

    Vector3::Vector3(double data[3]) : x(data[0]), y(data[1]), z(data[2])
    {
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator+=(const Vector3& rhs)
    {
        this->x += rhs.x;
        this->y += rhs.y;
        this->z += rhs.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator-=(const Vector3& rhs)
    {
        this->x -= rhs.x;
        this->y -= rhs.y;
        this->z -= rhs.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator*=(const Vector3& rhs)
    {
        this->x *= rhs.x;
        this->y *= rhs.y;
        this->z *= rhs.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator/=(const Vector3& rhs)
    {
        this->x /= rhs.x;
        this->y /= rhs.y;
        this->z /= rhs.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator+=(double s)
    {
        this->x += s;
        this->y += s;
        this->z += s;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator-=(double s)
    {
        this->x -= s;
        this->y -= s;
        this->z -= s;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator*=(double s)
    {
        this->x *= s;
        this->y *= s;
        this->z *= s;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector3& Vector3::operator/=(double s)
    {
        this->x /= s;
        this->y /= s;
        this->z /= s;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

example - main.cpp

```
#include "aml.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    aml::Vector3 v1(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    aml::Vector3 v2(4.0, 5.0, 6.0);

    aml::Vector3 v3 = v1 + v2;

    aml::Vector3 v4 = v1 * v2;

    std::cout << "v1 : " << v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v2 : " << v2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v3 : " << v3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v4 : " << v4 << std::endl;
}
```

test - main.cpp

```
//File is empty
```

aml_vector3_test.cpp

```
#include <catch2/catch_all.hpp>
#include "aml.h"
```

---

Final Update (Solution)

I solved the problem by reinstalling vcpkg package manager and cmake tool.

Comment: Have you checked that the `catch_all` header is actually in the package? I think it's optional. Have you checked that `CATCH2_INCLUDE_DIRS` is defined?

Comment: @AlanBirtles catch_all.hpp is present in the package manager installed directory. It was the first thing I had checked, Location : D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\catch2. When I created project using MsBuild build system, the catch2 library is getting detected.

Comment: @AlanBirtles `CATCH2_INCLUDE_DIRS` is pointing to `D:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include`

Comment: have you checked that the includes are being set correctly in the generated projects?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I couldn't understand what you are trying to convey. I 've checked in the `test` project. The include path is getting displayed properly.

Comment: if the includes are set in the generated project then I don't think there's much more we can do without a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Catch2 is the testing framework https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2. I have commented all my code but still getting same error. I created an empty blank project and imported tried importing Catch2 and plog (another library) but I am getting same error. Is their anything else that I need to check? I have also added code to my other files.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have updated the question and add all my code,=.